# Installing custom ROM with twrp | error executing updater binary in zip

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp

I have a rooted HTC One X with stock Ice Cream Sandwich (4.2.2) and I want to install crDroid ROM. I've tried to install multiple times, I've wiped Dalvik-system-data-cache, and every time I get *error executing updater binary in zip (name of rom zip)*.

I have been searching for solution online for hours, but I didn't find anything that works for me. TWRP can't mount usb-otg (if it is related)

Comment: Is there any error-code? If so, please edit your question and include it. May be a bad download or a assertion fail.

Comment: Since you're trying to flash custom ROM on a stock ROM, try flashing latest firmware then install the ROM( Flash  `boot.img` inside the new crDroidROM.zip first with `fastboot flash boot boot.img` and then go to custom recovery install new crDroid rom)